# SQL - How to change data type float to nvarchar and remove scientific notation

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I change the data type float to nvarchar in order to remove the scientific notation and still keep precision? Consider the following:

```
CREATE TABLE ConversionDataType (ColumnData FLOAT);

INSERT INTO ConversionDataType VALUES (25566685456126);
INSERT INTO ConversionDataType VALUES (12345545546845);
INSERT INTO ConversionDataType VALUES (12345545545257);
```

When I do a simple read I get the following data, as expected:

```
select * from ConversionDataType 

ColumnData
------------------------------------
 25566685456126
 12345545546845
 12345545545257
```

Now when I try update the data type to an nvarchar, it gets stored in scientific notation which is something I don't want:

```
update ConversionDataType
set ColumnData = CAST(ColumnData AS NVARCHAR)
```

The result set is as follows:

```
25566700000000
12345500000000
12345500000000
```

It replaces some digits and adds zeros after the 6th index. How can I go about this? I had a look at the Convert function but that is only for converting date time data types.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQL Server. Its company standard to have this field as an nvarchar. I am moving over the table to production and it needs to be an nvarchar. The actual column is for cellphone numbers and sometimes we often get them with their prefixed dialing codes (e.g in South Africa, the number will be prefixed with +27) hence it needs to be in nvarchar.

Comment: A [`float`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql) has a maximum of 15 digits of precision. So even before we start, you're out of luck since your second value has more digits than that.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's okay because the actual values have 15 as maximum length. Hence I used Float to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FLOAT` was a very bad decision as this is not a precise data type. If you wanted to store the phone numbers as numbers, you'd have to go for `DECIMAL` instead.

But you'll have to use `NVARCHAR` instead. And this is the only reasonable design, as phone numbers can have leading zeros or start with a plus sign. So the first thing is to introduce an `NVARCHAR` column:

```
ALTER TABLE ConversionDataType ADD ColumnDataNew NVARCHAR(30);
```

The function to convert a number into a string in SQL Server is `FORMAT`. It lets you state the format you want to use for the conversion, which is integer in your case (a simple `'0'`):

```
update ConversionDataType set ColumnDataNew = format(ColumnData, '0');
```

At last remove the old column and then rename the new one with the same name. SQL Server lacks an `ALTER TABLE` syntax to rename a column, so we must call `sp_RENAME` instead (at least this is what I have read on the Internet; here is a link to the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188351.aspx).

```
ALTER TABLE ConversionDataType DROP COLUMN ColumnData;
EXEC sp_RENAME 'ConversionDataType.ColumnDataNew', 'ColumnData', 'COLUMN';
```

Here you can see the results: http://rextester.com/GLLB27702

Comment: One last thing though, is it possible to reorder the columns?

Comment: Reorder columns? You mean that the table definition changes from `mytable(col1, col2)` to `mytable(col2, col1)`? I don't know. You can make this a new request, if this is important for you. You'd certainly find somebody who knows the answer.

Comment: Precisely. I figured it out though. You do it in the designer in SSMS by dragging the columns to the desired index. However this can be a pain if the table has set restrictions (I encountered them). Thus I created a new table with the desired table ordering then copied over the data using insert into command.

Answer (score 4):

Being valid what others said in comment, if you just want to convert float to varchar without scientific notation, you need to convert to numeric. You can try this:

```
  SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST(25566685456126291 AS FLOAT) AS NUMERIC) AS NVARCHAR)
```

Output:

```
C1
------------------------------
25566685456126292
```

Whereas

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(25566685456126291 AS FLOAT)  AS NVARCHAR) AS C1
```

gives:

```
C1
------------------------------
2.55667e+016
```

If you need to change datatype, I think you should add a new column, update it and (if you want) delete the old column and rename the new column at the end.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST1 (C1 FLOAT)
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES (25566685456126291);

ALTER TABLE TEST1 ADD C2 VARCHAR(18)
UPDATE TEST1 SET C2=CAST(CAST(C1 AS NUMERIC) AS VARCHAR)

  SELECT * FROM TEST1
```

Output:

```
C1                     C2
---------------------- ------------------
2.55666854561263E+16   25566685456126292
```

Comment: But when you're selecting you're just reading the data from the table. I want to update the column data type in its table definition too. It needs to maintain the data and keep its precision but be stored as nvarchar as opposed to a float.

Comment: I think you can't with a single command.  Maybe you need to specify better what you want to do in your question.

Comment: My question has an update command though. I want to change the float data type to nvarchar and still persist the data without it being change to scientific notation when I cast it. If I was just reading the data then your solution using the select command would have worked.

Comment: Since you know where I am going wrong, how about you steer me in the right direction? Because the Alter Column statement just truncates the data..

Comment: I added something to my answer but please, next time, do some more effort to write your question in better way.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(250), StudentID) FROM TableA
```

StudentID is your Float Column of database

or Simply use

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(250), yourFloatVariable)
```